# Flutter : I have error when work with tow dropdown button load one from another

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i am work with flutter drop down menu . firs menu for location . and second for sublocation . it is work when click on first location but when change to second and click second  location this error appear "'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 620 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not true.
"

my variable

```
  //location
  String _myLocation ; 
  List data = List(); 
  //sublocation
  String _mySublocation  ; 
  List data2 = List();
```

function for location

```
Future  getLocation() async {
   try{
      var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull("http://iraqdoctors.com/api/locations"), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    setState(() {
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      data = resBody;
    });
    return "Sucess";
   }catch(e){

   }
  }//get location
```

function for sublocation

```
Future  getSublocation() async {
    try{
      var res2 = await http
        .post(Uri.encodeFull("http://iraqdoctors.com/api/getlocationflutter"),
         headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
         body: {
            "cityname":"$_myLocation",  
          } 
         );   
    setState(() {
      var resBody2 = json.decode(res2.body);
      data2 = resBody2;
    });
    return "Sucess";
    }catch(e){

    }
  }//get sublocation
```

Location dropdown

```
 Container(     
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:10), 
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(           
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
      ),
       child:DropdownButton( //location                  
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            iconSize: 24,
            elevation: 16,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),            
            value: _myLocation,
            items: data.map((item) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item['city'],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                value: item['city'],
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: ( newVal) {
              setState(() {
                _myLocation = newVal;  
                getSublocation();              
              });
            },     
            isExpanded: true,
             underline: SizedBox(),                       
            iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
            hint: Text('اختر المدينة',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),    
        ),),
```

Sublocation dropdown

````
 Container(        
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:10),       
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(           
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
      ),
       child:  DropdownButton(//sublocation           
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            iconSize: 24,
            elevation: 16,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18) ,           
            items: data2.map((item) {               
                return new DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item['state'],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                value: item['id'].toString(),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                    _mySublocation = value  ;        
               });
            },
             value: _mySublocation ,
             isExpanded: true,
             hint: Text('اختر المنطقة',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),), 
             underline: SizedBox(),
             iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
            ),),
                 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use 2 seconds delay to simulate your http task 
The error message means `data2` is null 
In your `onChanged`, you need to await `await getSublocation()` 
and make sure convert json to `data2` is correct

code snippet

```
onChanged: (newVal) async {
                  _myLocation = newVal;
                  await getSublocation();
                  setState(() {});
                },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String _myLocation = null;
  List data = List();
  //sublocation
  String _mySublocation = null;
  List data2 = List();

  Future getLocation() async {
    try {
      /* var res = await http.get(
          Uri.encodeFull("http://iraqdoctors.com/api/locations"),
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
      setState(() {
        var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
        data = resBody;
      });*/
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {});
      data.clear();
      data.add({"city": "A"});
      data.add({"city": "B"});
      setState(() {});
      return "Sucess";
    } catch (e) {}
  } //get location

  Future getSublocation() async {
    try {
      /*var res2 = await http.post(
          Uri.encodeFull("http://iraqdoctors.com/api/getlocationflutter"),
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
          },
          body: {
            "cityname": "$_myLocation",
          });
      setState(() {
        var resBody2 = json.decode(res2.body);
        data2 = resBody2;
      });*/
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {});

      String jsonString = '''
      [ { "id": 1, "state": "الحارثية", "city": "بغداد", "created_at": "2019-12-17 07:20:16", "updated_at": "2019-12-17 07:20:16" } ] 
      ''';

      data2.clear();
      data2 = json.decode(jsonString);
      /*data2.clear();
      data2.add({"state": "A1", "id": "a1"});
      data2.add({"state": "B1", "id": "b1"});*/
      print(data2.toString());
      print(data2[0]['state'].toString());
      setState(() {});
      return "Sucess";
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  } //get sublocation

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getLocation();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                ),
              ),
              child: DropdownButton(
                //location
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                value: _myLocation,
                items: data.map((item) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(' ${item['city']} ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    value: item['city'],
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (newVal) async {
                  _myLocation = newVal;
                  await getSublocation();
                  setState(() {});
                },
                isExpanded: true,
                underline: SizedBox(),
                iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
                hint: Text(
                  'اختر المدينة',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                ),
              ),
              child: DropdownButton(
                //sublocation
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                items: data2.map((item) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(' ${item['state']}',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    value: item['id'].toString(),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _mySublocation = value;
                  });
                },
                value: _mySublocation,
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text(
                  'اختر المنطقة',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                underline: SizedBox(),
                iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i try your code but same error appear lock my gif screen shoot

Comment: print resBody2 and data2 to check what you get. the error means your data2 is null or incorrect

Comment: when i delete value it work fine mean ...  value:  item['state'], ... my problem with this value

Comment: and now i working  with this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_formfield#-readme-tab- ....... and same error with value

Comment: is data2 a map? if data2 is a map does it have state attribute. you can see my example. I use data2.add({"state": "A1", "id": "a1"}); to add attribute.

Comment: yes it is map . this post json reslut .....[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "state": "الحارثية",
        "city": "بغداد",
        "created_at": "2019-12-17 07:20:16",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-17 07:20:16"
    }
]

Comment: works fine with static string. you can see my updated answer. In onChanged , do you await getSubLocation?

Comment: yes i awaited it . but i think there is another reason !!

Comment: Finally . solved . just add this .... _mySublocation = " " ;  ..... to location dropdown on change

Comment: You can also use String _mySublocation = null; see my example