# Depending Dropdown failing assert error when you go back to change the first dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying the code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AUuhhSakro (or the github: https://github.com/khaliqdadmohmand/flutter_dynamic_dropdownLists/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

The issue is that when we (the viewers of the video) tries to "go back" to change the initial state (not app state, like county or province), the app crashes with this error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 14. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 827 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

I believe the problem is when the dropdown is built the first time, it can have a null string as the `value` parameter of the dropdown, but the second time around it crashes on the assert (if you set it to null you crash at `value==null` and if you don't reset the variable you are using for `value` then in the new dropdownlist this value is not in the items. (where the count has to be `== 1`)

This has been racking my brain in my own project too, I thought I had it working, but apparently it's still very much broken.

[Flutter : I have error when work with tow dropdown button load one from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604124/flutter-i-have-error-when-work-with-tow-dropdown-button-load-one-from-another)

This is a similar problem and that solution has an async in it (but this is simply not working for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can in `onChanged` add `_myCity = null;` 
code snippet

```
onChanged: (String Value) {
      setState(() {
        _myState = Value;
        _myCity = null;
        _getCitiesList();
        print(_myState);
      });
    },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getStateList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dynamic DropDownList REST API'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, top: 100),
            child: Text(
              'KDTechs',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          //======================================================== State

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _myState,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select State'),
                        onChanged: (String Value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myState = Value;
                            _myCity = null;
                            _getCitiesList();
                            print(_myState);
                          });
                        },
                        items: statesList?.map((item) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: Text(item['name']),
                                value: item['id'].toString(),
                              );
                            })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),

          //======================================================== City

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _myCity,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select City'),
                        onChanged: (String Value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myCity = Value;
                            print(_myCity);
                          });
                        },
                        items: citiesList?.map((item) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: Text(item['name']),
                                value: item['id'].toString(),
                              );
                            })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //=============================================================================== Api Calling here

//CALLING STATE API HERE
// Get State information by API
  List statesList;
  String _myState;

  String stateInfoUrl = 'http://cleanions.bestweb.my/api/location/get_state';
  Future<String> _getStateList() async {
    await http.post(stateInfoUrl, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }, body: {
      "api_key": '25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad',
    }).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

//      print(data);
      setState(() {
        statesList = data['state'];
      });
    });
  }

  // Get State information by API
  List citiesList;
  String _myCity;

  String cityInfoUrl =
      'http://cleanions.bestweb.my/api/location/get_city_by_state_id';
  Future<String> _getCitiesList() async {
    await http.post(cityInfoUrl, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }, body: {
      "api_key": '25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad',
      "state_id": _myState,
    }).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      setState(() {
        citiesList = data['cities'];
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok... I got it to work using DropdownButtonHideUnderline and ButtonTheme in my code. But I was using a DropdownButtonFormField in my code before, and with that widget it didn't work... I really want the inputDecoration I get with the form field (to unify the UI with the TextFormField I use in other places), but if I can't have that, I'll change over to DropdownButtonUnderline. (I'm marking the answer correct, but I am wondering about the followup)

Comment: Need to reproduce your question. could you post your reproduce code to a new question. thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652777/dropdownbuttonformfield-assertion-fails-where-dropdownbuttonhideunderline-doesn  I added the question here.